# creating relationships when using READ CSV in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a really simple CSV that I created so I can practice loading CSVs into Neo4j.

The CSV looks like this:

```
boxer_id    name      boxer_country total_wins  bdate   fought  fight_id    fight_location  outcome
1         Glass Joe   France            0       1/2/80    2      100          Las Vegas      L
2        Bald Bull    Turkey            2       2/3/81    1      100          Macao          W
3       Soda Popinski Russia            6       3/4/82    4      101          Atlantic City  L
4          Sandman    USA               9       4/5/83    3      101         Japan           W
```

I want to make 2 nodes, `boxer` and `fight`.

But I'm having trouble connecting the boxers to the fights.

Here's as far as I got:

[image]

As you can see, I successfully read in the nodes, but I don't know how to create the relationship between boxers and their boxing matches.

I want to do something like:

```
CREATE (boxer)-[:AGAINST]->(boxer)
```

but this doesn't make sense. I need to use the field `fought`, which encapsulates the information regarding who has faced who in the ring.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure how to do this in the context of READ CSV.

Here's my code:

```
// The goal here is to create a node called Boxer, and pull in properties.

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.bdate, '/') AS bdate
CREATE (b:boxer  {boxer_id: line.boxer_id})
SET b.byear= TOINT(bdate[2]),
    b.bmonth= TOINT(bdate[0]),
    b.bday = TOINT(bdate[1]),
    b.name = line.name,
    b.country = line.boxer_country,
    b.total_wins = TOINT(line.total_wins)


// Now we make a node called Fight
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv' AS line
CREATE (f:fight  {fight_id: line.fight_id, fight_loc: line.fight_location})

// Now we set relationships
// ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a few lines to match the boxers you already created and create relationships between them and the newly created fight. I am thinking something along these lines might work for you...

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv' AS line
MATCH (b1:boxer {boxer_id: line.boxer_id})
WITH line, b1
MATCH (b2:boxer {boxer_id: line.fought})
MERGE (f:fight  {fight_id: line.fight_id})
CREATE (b1)-[:AGAINST]->(b2)
CREATE (b1)-[:FOUGHT_IN]->(f)
CREATE (b2)-[:FOUGHT_IN]->(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just model fights as relationships between Boxer nodes, instead of creating the Fight nodes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS line
MERGE (b1:Boxer {boxer_id: line.boxer_id})
MERGE (b2:Boxer {boxer_id: line.fought})
CREATE (b1)-[f:fought]->(b2)
SET f.location = line.fight_location,
    f.outcome = line.outcome
```

However it probably makes more sense to model the fights as nodes, since they are events. In that case something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///text.csv' AS line
MATCH (b:Boxer {boxer_id: line.boxer_id})
MERGE (f:fight  {fight_id: line.fight_id})
ON CREATE SET f.location = line.fight_location
CREATE (b)-[r:FOUGHT_IN]->(f)
WITH r, CASE line.outcome WHEN "W" THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS win
FOREACH (x IN win | SET r.winner = TRUE)
```

Note here that we are storing the outcome of the fight as a property on the `:FOUGHT_IN` relationship.

**Edit** Updated to use `MERGE` to avoid creating duplicate Fight nodes. When using `MERGE` you should also create a uniqueness constraint: `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:Fight) ASSERT f.fight_id IS UNIQUE;` before running the import script.

Comment: could you take a peek at this? I think maybe I have to add some sort of uniqueness constraint? The fight nodes are appearing multiple times. Aside from that: what you did appears to work great!! http://imgur.com/szprEfq

Comment: Ah yeah - didn't realize the `fight_id`s were duplicated. Updated.

Comment: Here's an interesting problem -- the fight ID's actually *aren't* unique!! Looking at the `fight_ID` column, the values are 100, 100, and 101, 101. I get an error when I set the constraint.

Comment: Well they are unique in your data model, just not in the CSV file (one entry for each boxer in the fight). [Cypher `MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) is your friend here.

Comment: Ugh...not sure why I keep getting `Node 10 already exists with label fight and property "fight_id"=[100]`...when creating the fight node (after setting the constraint.)

Comment: Try to delete everything `MATCH (a) DETACH DELETE a;` then try the updated query with the `MERGE` statement.